# Error with publishing my ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net, ftp, visual-studio-2017

solved.
My solution: Build -> clean -> rebuild

---

I got host for my website and now I'm trying to upload the website's files via VS2017 using 'publish' feature of VS. I setup the connection with the host properly (Validate connection went successful..). But as the VS tries to upload my files it says:

```
Unable to add 'Content/homePage.css' to the Web site.  Unable to parse server response to PASV command.
```

This error message is shown for each file in my website. The above is just an example to such message. I'm using FTP publish method. My host is 000webhost

diagnostic log:

```
15/07/2018 08:56:08
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__88.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---

===================
```